# How to send a collection created with `getElementsByClassName` to my controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm struggling trying to send the collection that is generated by `getElementsByClassName` to my controller in VB.Net, MVC5.  This particular page is used to edit items by the user, and the same page is used for each item type.  Additionally all fields for all item types are stored in one table, which I believe makes using the default model binder not an option.  All fields have a unique identifying number that is used as their `id` in the view.

The script I'm using to gather the various fields:

```
function submitEdit(editRow) {
                alert('edit function');

                var edits = document.getElementsByClassName('edit');
                alert('get complete');
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < edits.length; i++) {
                    alert('in loop');
                    alert(edits[i].checked);
                }
```

I have played around with different alerts and I am getting the values I need in my collection.

This is the function I'm trying to pass the collection to:

```
Function EditConfirmation(edits As Collection) As ActionResult
```

I have tried to send this collection as a url parameter.  I also tried to pass it via ajax like so:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ViewDetails/EditConfirmation',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'edits': edits },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success");
                }
                .error(function (xhr, status) {
                    alert(status);
                })
            });
```

Is there a way to pass this collection to my controller, or is there some other way of doing this that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should really use console.log instead of alert.
2. It will be much easier for you to debug using a real debugger (check chrome's developers tools for [javascript debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)).
3. You have some error in your javascript code near `.error(function`

your code there should look like:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/ViewDetails/EditConfirmation',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'edits': edits },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (status) {
        alert(status);
    })
});
```

4. Your main problem is that `document.getElementsByClassName` gives you an array of DOM elements, and you cannot pass these elements directly to your server. You need to change them to data that you can send to the server (like strings/numbers/booleans/simple-objects/array of those.

I'm not sure what exactly you want to send, but here is an example that you can use:

```js
var edits = document.getElementsByClassName('edit');
var dataToSend = {};
for (i = 0; i < edits.length; i++) {
    dataToSend[edits[i]['name']] = edits[i].checked;
}
// Now you can use the object dataToSend (which is a simple object) as the data to send to the server
$.ajax({
    ...
    ...
    data: { 'edits': dataToSend },
    ...
    ...
});
```